# Print characters of corresponding digits without using any loop by using mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to print characters of corresponding digits without using any loop by using php or mysql query. I have one table named "test".

My table is,

[image]

If input = 011, output should be "thh". How to print like this without using any loop. Please help me.

Comment: Return the required rows which with PHP it can be returned as an array and then you could use the `implode` PHP function to join the array back into a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OR php?
You could also fill these arrays with SQL queries.

```
 $input  = "011";
    $digits     = array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9");
    $characters = array("t", "h", "i", "r", "u", "v", "o", "n", "a", "m");

    $newphrase = str_replace($digits, $characters, $input);


    echo $newphrase; //Output: thh
```

//Edit
Since you requested a plain SQL version, this might help.
But i'm not very good with SQL, i believe Leran's answer is way cleaner!
The difference is that i do not create an aux table and sorry to fail you but i used a loop!

```
    SET @input = "011";
    SET @input_len = CHAR_LENGTH(@input);

     DELIMITER $$
     DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_mysql_while_loop$$
     CREATE PROCEDURE test_mysql_while_loop()
     BEGIN
     DECLARE x  INT;
     DECLARE str  VARCHAR(255);

     SET x = 1;
     SET str =  '';

     WHILE x  <= @input_len DO
     SET @inputindex = substring(@input , x, 1);
     select test.character from test where test.digits = @inputindex INTO @translation;
     SET  str = CONCAT(str,@translation,'');
     SET  x = x + 1; 
     END WHILE;

     SELECT str as result;
     END$$
    DELIMITER ;

CALL test_mysql_while_loop();
```

Comment: Yes it works. Is there any possibilities with sql query?

Comment: how to implement this same concept in mysql query?

Answer (score 1):

As variant

```
create table test(`character` char(1),digits int);

insert test(`character`,digits)values('t',0),('h',1),('i',2),...,('m',9);

-- the auxiliary table
create table input_len(ln int);

insert input_len(ln) values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),...,(max_length_of_input);
```

A query

```
select
  group_concat(t.`character` ORDER BY l.ch_pos SEPARATOR '') result
from test t
join
  (
    select ln ch_pos,substr('0121',ln,1) digits
    from input_len
    where ln<=length('0121')
  ) l
on l.digits=t.digits
```

SQL Fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a731b/1